# .NET Core 2.2 Publish fails for missing *.pdb and *.xml

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish my project to a folder and I'm running into errors I've never seen before. It's complaining that *.pdb and *.xml files for Microsoft packages cannot be copied because they don't exist.

Here are a few samples.

Could not copy the file `"C:\Users\jvlahos\.nuget\packages\system.reactive.platformservices\3.1.1\lib\netcoreapp1.0\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.pdb" because it was not found.`

This is coming from two root locations.

`C:\Users\jvlahos\.nuget\packages\`

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\`

How can I either force the publish process to exclude the *.pdb and *.xml files (they aren't needed to run the application) or actually get those files?

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation I finally found the answer. I created the project from a template using `dotnet new` and at the bottom of the *.csproj file for the main project was this.

```
<Target Name="_ResolvePublishNuGetPackagePdbsAndXml" AfterTargets="RunResolvePublishAssemblies">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))" DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))" DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Not sure why it was even part of the template but that was it.